Is there any significance of India's "strategic partnership" with Poland to geopolitics?
India and Poland, in a joint statement, have declared establishment of a strategic partnership.
If I recall correctly, this is the first time India has established a strategic partnership with a country whose principal "enemy" is Russia, without a China angle (unlike US or Japan which are also rivals of China, Poland is not).
Given India's dependence on Russia (most weapons purchases, and recently, also oil purchases come from Russia) and and also historically great relations, will this strategic partnership strain India's Russia relations?

Without wanting to speculate, the significance is probably limited but existing.

Link's not working for me.

I would put this in the larger context that Modi wanted to (and did) visit Ukraine, relatively soon after visiting Moscow as well (in July). Since there are no flights to Kyiv [due to the war, still], all foreign leaders that did that in the past few years took a train from Poland.
And since no Indian leader had visited Poland in some 45 years, it would certainly have looked like a bit of a snub to not meet with anyone of import in Poland on that occasion.
As for the talks with Poland, reportedly they centered on a few themes:

immigration/visas (Poland has become in some sense a gateway to Europe for some Asian workers. And India is still a large exporter of workers, at least to the Gulf countries.)

food processing. India seems discontent with amount they're doing and looking for FDI in this area. Although said industry has experienced substantial growth in Poland in the past decade, TBH, I'm not sure how much India can expect from Poland directly as FDI, since said industry is dominated by some large (Western) European firms/conglomerates, which do however have plenty of factories in the Eastern parts of Europe these days. (OTOH the concentration has a pretty 'long tail', e.g. the first four firms have around 40% of the employees, according to one survey.)

defense. Reportedly India had to delay some plans to acquire more Russian weapons for now, due the increased  internal demand [in Russia] for their own production (again due to the war in Ukraine). Poland also has seen increased defense spending recently, as they were also moving away from legacy Soviet equipment. How much potential for cooperation directly with Poland on these matter there is for India, I'm again rather unsure. Wikipedia mentions that in the early 2000s, India bought a number of armored personnel carriers from Poland, but with competition between India and China being increasingly about high-tech weaponry, it's again mostly Western firms that India is probably most interested in attracting. Conversely, India has been boosting its own weapons production capabilities, but potential exports to Poland are again not terribly clear, as Poland has been mostly shopping for high-tech weapons form the US etc. OTOH, Poland did manage a few interesting deals/collaborations like the KRAB being a combination of Western, South Korean, and some domestic parts. So, possibly exploring some such arrangements with India mixed-in isn't out of the question.


So, all-in-all, there's probably more form than substance on a direct India-Poland cooperation on a number of these themes [for now], but perhaps both sides found it worth exploring some angles, given the opportunity.
On a more practical level, the "strategic partnership" did establish a Joint Commission for Economic Cooperation, to meet annually. A bit more searching finds that India has some similar commissions with Western countries (individually), e.g. one with Spain was set up some 13 years ago.
One of the things mentioned in the 'Action Plan' is that Poland 'recognizes' India's ambition  to join the  International Energy Agency. OTOH, that's (phrased) short of a full-throated support. So, trying to garner more support for that is/was probably among the goals of this visit as well.
Another interesting (perhaps) angle is that the Modi visit and meeting with PM Tusk was also on the heels of a visit to China by Poland's president Duda (also) in July. But Duda and Tusk are from opposing political parties, i.e. there's a "cohabitation" situation in Poland's government right now. (Somewhat surprisingly perhaps, although there's little disagreement in Poland on the position vis-a-vis Russia, there is some more of a spectrum of opinion relating to China. Duda apparently has been consistently part of the faction that is more favorable to enhanced ties with China, which perhaps didn't sit too well with India. The timing of the Modi visit, after Duda's party lost parliamentary control last fall is perhaps not coincidental in that respect either.)

Regarding food processing, you are citing a EU report that does not include the Polish meat industry. The by far largest meat company in Poland is not a Western conglomerate, but Animex, a subsidiary of Smithfields, in turn owned by Chinese WH group. They dominate the complete vertical stack related to pigs and also have capacities in beef and poultry. Whether that is of much interest to India is another question. But it shows that especially in Eastern Europe, Asian companies were able to gain a sizable foothold in food industries by buying into the socialist-era agricultural conglomerates.
